# Give a fixed position to an element to an oversize image

Tags: jquery, css, position

What if I have an oversized image, and I'd like to anchor an element to it in such a way that it only shows up when you have panned/scanned to that part of the image?

HTML:

```
<img id="map" src="images/big_image.jpg" alt="xxx" width="2160" height="589"/>
<div id="small_image" class="bridge"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#map {

 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 border-top: 1px solid gray;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 left:0;
 top: 0;
 z-index:1;

}

.bridge {
    position: absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:10; 
    border: 5px solid white;
}

#small_image {

    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background-image:url('images/small_image.jpg');

}
```

I'm using touchpanview ( http://www.consulenza-web.com/jquery/touchpanview/) to effect the pan and scan.

Any guidance / suggestions would be helpful, please.

Comment: On the page that you linked, is the "Map with pins" example similar to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, sort of -- I want the element to come into view only when you pan to that part.

Comment: In the end, I gave up this approach and used 'draggable' instead.